# I am unable to access any messenger site from Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am not able to access any messenger site through emulator even Gtalk also, so please help me if anybody knows.

Comment: Firewall? What emulator please?

Comment: Through Android emulator

Comment: Can you access a web site? Does the browser in the emulator loads web site? If not check the proxy settings in Settings page

Comment: Browser is working on emulator & i am able access any web site from browser.It's open connection no firewall & proxy.Only problem with messengers. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Messenger apps (like Google Talk or IM) they don't come on the emulator. This is because they work over the cellular company's SMS network (so they can charge you for messages) and not over the data network.